Primary constructors in the Azure function
I was having a azure function and it's working fine and I have changed that to primary constructor and it's working perfectly fine on my local envrionment but while deploying that using the

az functionapp

I am getting error

"ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'PushDeploymentController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Access to the path 'C:\home\LogFiles\kudu\deployment' is denied.","ExceptionType":"System.UnauthorizedAccessException","StackTrace":"   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)\r\n   at System.IO.Abstractions.DirectoryWrapper.CreateDirectory(String path)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.FileSystemHelpers.CreateDirectory(String path)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Environment.get_DeploymentTracePath()\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Web.App_Start.NinjectServices.GetLogger(IEnvironment environment, IKernel kernel) in C:\__w\1\s\Kudu.Services.Web\App_Start\NinjectServices.cs:line 807\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Web.App_Start.NinjectServices.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__13(IContext context) in C:\__w\1\s\Kudu.Services.Web\App_Start\NinjectServices.cs:line 279\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.CallbackProvider1.CreateInstance(IContext context)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Provider1.Create(IContext context)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()\r\n   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__f(IBinding binding)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2(ITarget target)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer1..ctor(IEnumerable1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()\r\n   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__f(IBinding binding)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2(ITarget target)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer1..ctor(IEnumerable1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()\r\n   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__f(IBinding binding)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Targe

My code before the change:
public class GreatClass
{
    private ICustomService _customService;

    public GreatClass(ICustomService customService)
    {
        _customService = customService;
    }

    [FunctionName("MyFunc")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%RunFrequency%", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer,
        // ICustomService customService, // Incorrect!
        ILogger log)
    {
        //Logic
    }
}

my function after the changes:
public class GreatClass(ICustomService customService)
{
    
    [FunctionName("MyFunc")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%RunFrequency%", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer,
        // ICustomService customService, // Incorrect!
        ILogger log)
    {
        //Logic
    }
}


Something that's definitely wrong with your code:
Note that Primary Constructors only became supported in C# 12 and therefore you need .NET 8 onwards.^1
Your code above has the attribute [FunctionName] which denotes In-process Functions, so it's a high likelihood you are using .NET 6.
So, the code in your question shouldn't be possible to compile.* This doesn't align with your statement that the code runs OK locally.
Reasons you might want to clarify your question:
Based on your invalid mix of .NET 6 with Primary Constructor, as mentioned above, I wonder if your question isn't an accurate enough representation of your real code.
My thoughts are reinforced because you have names like GreatClass and ICustomService. Please can you double-check that your question is representative of your actual code, e.g. you have specified the same Function vs FunctionName. Thanks!
Caveat.
*unless you've enabled In-process on .NET 8 but have forgotten to mention that key information; or unless you have accidentally given the wrong attribute in your dummy code sample above.
